# How to edit a long text in the WPF DataGrid (like memo-edit with drop-down)

Tags: wpf, text, datagrid, drop-down-menu, multiline

Assume you have a property of your ViewModel that is string and contains a long text.
The user want to edit this property in the in-place mode in your WPF DataGrid, so

- In the view mode the appropriated cell shows the text trimmed with elipsis
- In the editing mode the text will be opened in the drop-down for the cell. The drop-down should allow only the vertical scrolling.

So it should looks like:
[image]

My question is how to implement in the WPF DataGrid these requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Use Data templates and Style Triggers to achieve your requirements.

Comment: I've tried alredy the ComboBox in the DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate, and DataGridComboBoxColumn directly, but there are many unsolved problems. I want to use the property of the ViewModel directly and not to wrap it in any Collections for the ItemSource, and s.o. Can you please post your working xaml solution?

Comment: What you want to achieve is that if the grid is in view mode, then it will appear as a text trimmed with ellipsis if they are too long and in edit mode you want the text will open a drop down cell for the cell, and what does the combobox shows? Same as the view mode?

Comment: For the view mode this can be easy solved with e.g. the ElementStyle for TextBlock with TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis". But the main question is how to show the desired combobox (in edit mode or in both modes), that shows the text like on the image above.